# TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration (removing values from zipped list)

Tags: python

I am getting this error when I run my program and I have no idea why. The error occurs in the April value element where I try to remove only the last values from both the tot_vol and service lists. Below is the code I am running:

```
tot_vol = \[52766,16213,4224,59523,38375,80950,92839,215667,73676,259597,82342,19162\]
service = \[189,163,75,240,146,654,312,993,400,3189,1000,58\]

 occ_rate = {'Jan': [((t*seasonality[0])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service)],
             'Feb': [((t*seasonality[1])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service)],
             'Mar': [((t*seasonality[2])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip((tot_vol[6], tot_vol[11]), (service[6], service[11]))],
             'Apr': [((t*seasonality[3])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip(tot_vol[11], service[11])],
             'May': [((t*seasonality[4])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip((tot_vol[6], tot_vol[11]), (service[6], service[11]))],
             'Jun': [((t*seasonality[5])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip(tot_vol[11], service[11])],
             'Jul': [((t*seasonality[6])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip((tot_vol[6], tot_vol[11]), (service[6], service[11]))],
             'Aug': [((t*seasonality[7])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip(tot_vol[11], service[11])],
             'Sep': [((t*seasonality[8])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip(tot_vol[11], service[11])],
             'Oct': [((t*seasonality[9])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip(tot_vol[11], service[11])],
             'Nov': [((t*seasonality[10])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service)],
             'Dec': [((t*seasonality[11])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service)]}
```

and here is the error that I get when I run the code:

```
\---\> 25                     'Apr': \[((t*seasonality\[3\])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip(tot_vol\[11\], service\[11\])\],*
26                     'May': \[((tseasonality\[4\])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip((tot_vol\[6\], tot_vol\[11\]), (service\[6\], service\[11\]))\],
27                     'Jun': \[((t\*seasonality\[5\])/(s/n_months)/barge_cap/2) for (t, s) in zip(tot_vol, service) if (t, s) not in zip(tot_vol\[11\], service\[11\])\],

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Comment: Look at `zip(tot_vol[11], service[11])`. `tot_vol[11]` and `service[11]` are ints, so this does not make sense as a zip.

Comment: Have a careful look down the 2nd 'zip' column. Do you see where the typo is?

And then *please* come up with another way of writing this!  it's horribly unreadable--which is why the bug happened in the first place ;)

Comment: `zip` is a lazy evaluator. So instead of `zip((tot_vol[6], .....)` I suggest you try to do `list(zip((tot_vol[6], .....))` or explicit way is to do `[each for each in zip((tot_vol[6], .....)]`

Comment: @2e0byo, it's not a typo error, and yes I have tried to find a better way of writing it with no solution. I'sd be happy if you have a better and cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @khelwood, you're right. I see that the problem comes from the zip lists, but don't know how to go around it

Comment: @sam, thanks I'll try this

Comment: @Babz see my answer for how I would go about writing this kind of thing, although note that I have no idea what your data means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried to find a better way of writing it... I'd be happy if you have a better and cleaner way.

Sure.  Here are two approaches.  Please note that I have not the slightest idea what your data represents, I'm just refactoring what I think your code means.  You can probably come up with more intelligent names.

### Fully declarative

Suppose you wanted to keep the whole declarative dict literal.  Assuming your variables are defined (btw some are missing in that code snippet), there's clearly a calculation you can factor out:

```py
def calc_rate(t, s, seasonality):
    return (t * seasonality) / (s / n_months) / barge_cap / 2
```

(Incidentally refactoring the maths of that might make it neater, but I've left it as it was)

Now for some months we just map this over the data, but for others we exclude certain elements by index.  So let's be explicit about that:

```py
occ_rate = {
    "Jan": [calc_rate(t, s, seasonality[0]) for t, s in zip(tot_vol, service)],
    "Feb": [calc_rate(t, s, seasonality[1]) for t, s in zip(tot_vol, service)],
    # etc
}
excluded_months = {6, 11}
excluded_vol = [x for i, x in enumerate(tot_vol) if i not in excluded_months]
exluded_service = [x for i, x in enumerate(service) if i not in excluded_months]

ocr_rate["Mar"] = [
    calc_rate(t, s, seasonality[2]) for t, s in zip(excluded_vol, excluded_service)
]
# etc

excluded_months = {11}
excluded_vol = [x for i, x in enumerate(tot_vol) if i not in excluded_months]
exluded_service = [x for i, x in enumerate(service) if i not in excluded_months]


ocr_rate["Apr"] = [
    calc_rate(t, s, seasonality[3]) for t, s in zip(excluded_vol, excluded_service)
]
# etc
```

You'll have to add in the missing months.

### Using a mapping

Now, there's another pattern we've hard-coded: the iteration of `seasonality` by month.   If we store the variable information we need to build the dict---the months to exclude---in some kind of datastructure we can build the dict programatically.

```py
def exclude_months(*args) -> tuple:
    vol = [x for i, x in enumerate(tot_vol) if i not in args]
    serv = [x for i, x in enumerate(service) if i not in args]
    return vol, serv


mapping = {
    "Jan": (),
    "Feb": (),
    "Mar": (6, 11),
    "Apr": (11,),
    "May": (6, 11),
    "Jun": (11,),
    "Jul": (6, 11),
    "Aug": (11,),
    "Sep": (11,),
    "Oct": (11,),
    "Nov": (),
    "Dec": (),
}

ocr_rate = {}
for (month, exclude), season in zip(mapping.items(), seasonality):
    ocr_rate[month] = [
        calc_rate(t, s, season) for t, s in zip(*exclude_months(*exclude))
    ]
```

In this case we just focus on encoding the variable bit---the months we exclude---and let code do the rest of the work.  Fewere chances for typos, but obviously the code has to work. Since I have no real data I can't test it...

There are plenty of other ways of writing most of these steps, but something like this is IMHO a lot more readable and lot more maintainable than a massive number of listcomps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these insights. The first approach worked fine, and I also leant a new method :)

Comment: Both should be identical. But it's possible there's a typo or silly mistake somewhere...  **edit** found and fixed an idiot bug, sorry.  Anyhow, if this fixed it, feel free to accept so the q stops showing as unanswered :)

Comment: thanks. Just for learning purposes, any reason why the mapping approach runs only until Apr, and not for the rest of the months?

Comment: @Babz no: perhaps a typo your end?  I can't reproduce it, and in any case it would make no sense.  Try printing your `mapping.keys()`.

Comment: It's my computer acting up. It did work correctly now after restarting. Thanks a lot for your help!